# Appears nextUntil argument is ignored

Tags: jquery

In the code below I expect to see the Red, Blue, Green and Brown rows displayed, but it appears all rows, except Red, are hidden as if the nextUntil argument is ignored. Any clues? Thanks.

After some research,I tried both

```
$("#firstrow").nextUntil('span[class="hues"]').hide();
```

and

```
$("#firstrow").nextUntil('span:not(.colors)').hide();
```

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"/>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#firstrow").nextUntil('span[class="hues"]').hide();
                //$("#firstrow").nextUntil('span:not(.colors)').hide();            
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="colortable">
            <tr id="firstrow">
                <span class="colors">Red</span>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <span class="colors">Orange</span>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <span class="hues">Blue</span>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <span class="shades">Green</span>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <span class="colors">Brown</span>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.nextUntil()` searched siblings, and your span is not a sibling of `#firstrow`.

Comment: Also, your HTML is *horribly* broken: a `tr` can have only `th` and `td` elements as children. Anything else, such as a `span` should be wrapped in one of those elements.

Comment: David Thomas - Yeah, I know better, but in a haste to get this posted somehow I omitted the td's. My test file included the td's but has the same issue. Thanks.

Comment: j08691 - I see. I was thinking the nextUntil would search all siblings until it found a sibling with span[class="hues"] as a descendant. I need to study and experiment more. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup is invalid, `tr` elements should only have `td` child elements.

```
<table id="colortable">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="firstrow">
            <td> 
                <span class="colors">Red</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Span elements are not sibling of the selected element, `nextUntil` only filters the next sibling elements of the selected element, you should select the `tr` that has that specific span element:

```
// Select the all next sibling elements until the first element that matches the selector
$("#firstrow").nextUntil('tr:has(span.hues)').hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KDKeF/

If you want to select all the next sibling elements that match the selector, you can use `nextAll` method:

```
// Select the all next sibling elements that match the selector
$("#firstrow").nextAll('tr:has(span.hues)').hide();
```

Comment: Undefined - that adds more clarification; because #firstrow is a tr, I thought it was implicit that all the siblings would be trs, but apparently i need to be specific about the relationship of the span to the sibling tr's. your example on jsfiddle was a great help. Thanks. I will study this more.